# MySQL - how to insert values from one table into another with string matching?

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL noob here; looked around first but couldn't find the answer to this question.

So I have two tables in MySQL, one (Table1) which consists of one column containing unique list of names (Col1) and another containing corresponding binary values (Col2). The second table (Table2) contains a list of recurring names with a empty column waiting to be filled with binary values from the first table. What I want to do is, for each instance of a recurring name in Table2, insert the binary value from Col2 associated with the matching unique name in Table1.

I know how to do this in Excel—you just place the following VLOOKUP statement next to every row containing a recurring name. In the following code snippet A2 is a recurring name, unique names are contained in column B, and the binary values are contained in column C.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$B$2:$C$106095,2,FALSE)
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to reproduce this effect in MySQL. I can't use Excel because there's too much data. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be easier if you tell us the exact table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want something like this (I don't know what the Excel statement does):

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
SET table2.col2 = table2.col2
WHERE table2.col2 IS NULL
```

This will update each row `table2` that has `col2` empty, searching for the corresponding row in `table1` based on matching `col1` columns.

Btw, do you have a reason to do this? Why not just join both tables when selecting the data? For example:

```
SELECT table2.col1, table1.col2
FROM table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
```

Comment: Thanks guy! The second command worked—the first one returned nothing. Now, to see how long it will take to execute on >100K records...

Comment: @darkfaculties: Placing an index on the columns used in a join will typically speed the process up greatly when dealing with large amounts of data.  Not that 100K records is "large".

Comment: The first one is not supposed to return anything, it will just update the second table. I guess this is a terminology misunderstanding. :)